# OkHttp PUT request fails, but same request works in Postman

Tags: java, request, postman, okhttp

I've been struggling with this problem for quite some time, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have a postman put request that works perfectly. I want to do the same request with Spring RestTemplate. Since this did not work, I tried using the postman code generator to get an OKHttp put request. Unfortunately this does not work either.

This is the Postman Request with Header: https://i.stack.imgur.com/56FPh.jpg (It doesnt have any authentication its just the headers and the body)

This is the Postman Request with Body: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tP2Z.jpg

And this is my code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().followRedirects(false)
            .build();
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");

    //body json
    JsonObject innerObject = new JsonObject();
    innerObject.addProperty("password", "12345678");
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.add("psuData", innerObject);

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jsonObject.toString(), mediaType);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://192.168.56.103:8089/v1/consents/" + consentId + "/authorisations/" + authorisationId)
            .put(body)
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHeader("X-Request-ID", "2f77a125-aa7a-45c0-b414-c3a25a116135")
            .addHeader("PSU-ID", "test")
            .addHeader("tpp-qwac-certificate", "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----")
            .build();
    Response response1 = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I get the other information for the request from the post requests, and they work fine. Can this be a problem because of a cross origin?

Put Request:

```
HttpHeaders headers = buildHeader(objectNodeTestCase.get(strHeader));
    HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestBody, headers);

    Map<String, String> pathVars = new HashMap<>(2);
    pathVars.put("consent-id", consentId);
    pathVars.put("authorisation-id", authorisationId);

    UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(mainLink.toUri())
            .path("/consents/{consent-id}/authorisations/{authorisation-id}")
            .buildAndExpand(pathVars);

    ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri.toString(), HttpMethod.PUT, request, Object.class);
```

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 : [no body]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:105) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:170) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:112) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:785) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:586) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at com.kamysek.berlingroup.controller.BerlinGroupLogicController.updateConsentsPsuData_PWD(BerlinGroupLogicController.java:262) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Can you please add the stack trace when you try to request the remote API or is there any error in the logs?

Comment: @rieckpil I added the stack trace. Do you have an idea what Im doing wrong?

Comment: the stack trace you posted is for using the `RestTemplate`, do you also have it for the `OkHttpClient`?

Comment: How to you launch your application? Is it maybe inside a Docker container and therefore not able to reach the IP?

Comment: It doesnt give me a stack trace.

Comment: I have multiple rest assured test cases and this is in one test case. The IP is reachable since I have to do other requests before and they work perfectly

Comment: Can you then please add how you create your `RestTemplate`

Comment: The body / header values all seem to be correct.

Comment: Given the stack trace for the `RestTemplate`, the remote service returns 401. That means you are not properly authenticated. Is the authentication done with this certificate in the header?

Comment: Yes, the postman also make the same request and there it work. Its the same head/body, there is no difference. The postman does not use authorization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209291/discussion-between-tryhard-and-rieckpil).